# How do I get the ID of a model instance into an Action Cable channel param hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

The [Rails Action Cable overview](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) states the following:

> If you have a stream that is related to a model, then the broadcasting
>   used can be generated from the model and channel. The following
>   example would subscribe to a broadcasting like
>   `comments:Z2lkOi8vVGVzdEFwcC9Qb3N0LzE`

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    post = Post.find(params[:id]).   # This is the line I'm trying to copy.
    stream_for post
  end
end
```

This is *exactly* what I want to do for one of my models (I have a model `Incident` that has many `Messages`, therefore I am making a `MessagesChannel`). However, I don't understand how the `:id` param was passed in this scenario. I know that the first argument of the `App.cable.subscriptions.create` call in the client-side CoffeeScript is passed to the server-side code as the params hash, but since the CoffeeScript is called on every page of the application, how do I know whether I am looking at an Incident page (because the ID could refer to another model if we're on a different page, or not be present at all), and how do I get the Incident ID into the channel params?

My (incorrect) attempt was this:

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "MessagesChannel", id: <%= params[:id] %> },
    connected: ->
        # ...
    # ...
```

And if I'm doing this wrong altogether, feel free to let me know the correct way.